# DC wiring graphic - does the current flow equally on the positive and negative wires?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

We have a solar lighting application, solar panels charge batteries in day, batteries power lights at night.  the wire size to the lights is small, 16 guage stranded, we had originally combined the 4 negative wires at the top of the mast (32 feet from batteries) and ran individual positive switched wires.

we later ran individual 16 guage negative wires without combining them at the top and found the light did not last as long.  is this related?  same wire, only difference is the negatives were combined at the top of the mast, so my question is in a DC circuit does the positive and negative both carry current and an equal amount?

Comment: Have you eliminated all confounding factors?

Answer (score 0):

> **in a DC circuit does the positive and negative both carry current and an equal amount?**

Yes. In a simple "series" circuit, all parts of the circuit carry the same current.

[image]

If there are multiple paths, the current will be distributed across them according to their variation in resistance.

---

Useful references

- [Wikipedia - Kirchoff's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_current_law_.28KCL.29)
- [BBC Bitesize - Useful circuits](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/standard/physics/using_electricity/useful_circuits/revision/1/)

Comment: "Yes. In a simple circuit, all parts of the circuit carry the same current." What is your definition of "simple" here? It must be no junctions or a single path.

Comment: @Gremlin. Yes, answer updated to make this clearer.